# how to get petals and sepals from iris data using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

> i'm really confused about that code... i'm new to python and just want to add petals and sepals from iris data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
%matplotlib inline
iris = load_iris()
features = iris.data.T

##################
what would be the code of petals and sepals in a scatter plot?

##################
plt.xlabel(iris.feature_names[0])
plt.ylabel(iris.feature_names[1]);
```

Comment: e.g. `plt.scatter(features[0], features[1])` for sepal width vs sepal length, see `iris.feature_names` for all feature names